# How to send numpad key with SendKeys.SendWait()?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am trying to send `NumPad8` key to other active window with `SendKeys.SendWait("{NUMPAD8}");`.

My problem is, that this key is not being sent.

`{Up}` works, even `{NUMPADDIV}` works. `NUMPAD0`-`NUMPAD9` doesn't...

Where could be the problem?

Comment: I don't see any of those values in the [SendKeys documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Why not just send the literals `0` to `9`?

Comment: How to send literals 0 - 9?

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait("1234567890");` Just use the values 0-9 across the top of your keyboard.

Comment: Well, that doesn't work either. I need it to click the number.
EDIT: It worked for 0, but not for 8.

Comment: Maybe the application isn't responding to the number 8 the way you expect it to? Anyways, you will need to P/Invoke the [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function yourself. [Here's an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd-event-funct) on how to use the function, and [here's the P/Invoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event).

Comment: SendKeys doesn't use physical keyboard buttons... ^^
Thanks anyway.